# How the parameters in Gradient Descent are initialized, when we build a model using Linear Regression?

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent

When I build a linear regression model in python or R, I just use the **fit** method. This method does not ask for initializing the learning rate, or starting point while this is required in gradient descent (as far as I know). So if I assume that the model is using Gradient descent to optimize, how these parameters are choosen by the linear model when using **fit** method?

Or, if the model does not use gradient descent (or its any type), then which algorithm it uses (and how) to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [lm.fit()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/lm.fit) method. This method uses [QR Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) technique for the [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). This technique doesn't require setting learning rate and starting point parameters.